# Designing a cube

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, cube, dimensional-modeling

I’ve been asked create our analysis cube and have a design question.

We sell ‘widgets’ and ‘parts’ to go with those widgets.  Each order has many widgets and sometimes a few parts.

What I’m stuck on is – to me, an order is a fact in a measure.  But, what are the widgets?  Are they a dimension and each fact in the measure will be an entry for every part and widget for the order.

So, if order 123 had widget 1 and widget 2 and part 5, then there will be 3 facts in the measure for the same order?  Is that correct?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Thank you!  The answers have been very helpful!

Comment: If any answer in particular was helpful, it's appropriate to mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

At its basic level you can consider most facts to be transactions or transaction line items. So, for example, you may have a 'sales' fact table in which each record represents one line item from that sale. Each fact record would have numeric columns representing metrics and other columns joining to dimension tables. The combination of those dimensions would describe that line item. So, in your case, you likely have something like:
1) A 'date' dimension detailing the date of the transaction
2) A 'widget' dimension detailing the widget sold on that transaction
3) A 'customer' dimension detailing the customer who bought that item (almost certainly the same customer would appear on every line item for this transaction)
4) ... determined by what information you have and what business problem you're trying to solve.

Now, the dimension tables contain further details. For example, your widget dimension table likely contains things like the name of the widget, the color, the manufacturer, etc. Every time your company sells one of these widgets, the record in the fact table links to that same dimension record for that name, color, manufacturer, etc. combination (i.e. you don't create a new dimension record every time you sell the same item - this is a one-to-many relationship - each dimension record may have many related fact records).

You other dimension tables would similarly describe their dimensions. For example, the customer dimension might give the customer's name, their address, ...

So, the short answer to your question is that widget likely is a dimension, items and widgets may (or may not) actually be the same dimension (in a school class I suspect that they are), and that you would have 3 fact records for that one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably along the same lines as the prior answer but....

If you try and model "many widgets per order" you'll have issues because you end up with a many (order fact) to many (widgets) relationship. In a cube / star schema design, many to many relationship usually need to be moddeled out to be many to one in some way.

So what you do is try and identify what special thing identifies an "order" (as opposed to a bunch of widgets in an order). Usually that is simply stuff like order date, customer, order number, tax

An example way to model this is:

If you have a single order with five widgets, you model that as a fact table with five records that happens to have a repeating widget, customer, date etc. in it

Then you have to work out how you spread an order header tax amount over five records. The two obvious solutions are:

1. Create a widget that represents tax and add that as another record
2. Spread the tax over five records, either evenly or weighted by something

Modelling "parts" just takes these concepts further.

It is important to understand what the end user wants to see, why they want to see parts. What do they want to measure by parts, how do you assign higher level values (like tax) down to lower levels like parts.